# List all sites and their database names in powershell

Tags: database, powershell, iis, scripting, database-migration

I'm quite new in powershell and I have a problem.
I'm doing migration of databases on new server, and I need to know for each website on IIS which database use. Because some sites use the same database and I need to migrate it at same time. 
Because I have too much sites to check their connection string, I want to make PS script to list all sites and their database name.

I already searched for solution, but I could't find it.
I found only commands for list all sites, states, bindings.
Import-Module Webadministration                                         Get-ChildItem -Path IIS:\Sites

Thank you very much.

Regards,
Jaka.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script can help you but The script written in PowerShell 4 assuming that the web.config file exists is tested in PowerShell 4.

```
Import-Module WebAdministration

Get-ChildItem -Path IIS:\Sites | `
ForEach-Object {

    $webConfigFile = [xml](Get-Content "$($_.PhysicalPath)\Web.config")

    foreach($connString in $webConfigFile.configuration.connectionStrings.add)
    {
        $dbRegex = "(((Data Source)))\s*=(?<ic>[a-z\s0-9]+?);"
        $found = $connString.connectionString -match $dbRegex
        if ($found)
        {
            Write-Host "Database: $($Matches["ic"])"
        }
    }}
```

Comment: Thank you M.Fatih for your answer.
Would you please tell me how to check if file Web.config does not exist in site directory? And one more question, it si possible to use Out-GridView for all data like (sitename, status, bindings, database name)?
Thank you very much.
Regards, Jack

Comment: Hey, would you please explain me how this line works: $dbRegex = "(((Data Source)))\s*=(?<ic>[a-z\s0-9]+?);"

Comment: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Paste regex expressin '(((Data Source)))\s*=(?<ic>[a-z\s0-9]+?);' into the  
'regex101.com' site and paste connection expression 'connectionString="Data Source=DB1;User Id=bilinmiyor;Password=123;Pooling=true;Min Pool Size=5;Max Pool Size=400;Connection Lifetime=30"' in the lower box and look at the right side. Note: regex flag : gmi

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/MIafzn/2